# Subscribe to Dynamic Messages

Tags: nservicebus

Here is my scenario:

We have a central office and a number of locations (50 and growing).  We have messages that are currently published from the central office that machines in the locations subscribe to.  Currently each location will receive all published messages of this type.  The messages have a locationnumber property that identifies which location a particular message is relevant to, and on the clients at the location any messages that don't have the matching locationnumber are ignored.  What I would like to do is to dynamically create a message class based on which location the subscriber is located and have it subscribe to that type of message.  The publisher would then inspect data and generate the "same" dynamic message class(not sure if this would match, haven't got that far in the process yet) and publish that message, so that only the locations that are actually interested in that message have it sent to them.  Is this possible to do?  Am I going about this completely wrong for NServiceBus, is there another method of doing this type of filtering?
I'm currently stuck at trying to subscribe to the dynamic type I've created, I get this error when I try:

`No destination could be found for message type DerivedClassOne. Check the <MessageEndpointMappings> section of the configuration of this endpoint for an entry either for this specific message type or for its assembly.`

Here's my config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <UnicastBusConfig DistributorControlAddress="" DistributorDataAddress="" ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <!-- publishers don't need to set this for their own message types -->
      <add Messages="NSBDynamicSubscriptionSpike.Messages" Endpoint="basequeue" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="MessageClassName" value="DerivedClassOne"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here's my code:

```
namespace NSBDynamicSubscriptionSpike.Messages
{
    public class BaseMessageClass : IMessage
    {
        public string BaseStringProp { get; set; }
        public int BaseIntProp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace NSBDynamicSubscriptionSpike.Server
{
    public class MessageHandler : AsA_Server,
        IWantCustomInitialization,
        IConfigureThisEndpoint,
        IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
    {
        private Type myMessageType;

        public IBus Bus { get; set; }

        public void Handle(BaseMessageClass message)
        {
            BaseMessageClass m = (BaseMessageClass) message;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message type: {0}", m.GetType()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", m.BaseIntProp, m.BaseStringProp));
        }

        private bool HandleMessage(object message)
        {
            Handle((BaseMessageClass)message);
            return true;
        }


        public void Init()
        {
            NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .Log4Net()
                .MsmqTransport()
                .UnicastBus()
                .BinarySerializer()
                .InMemorySubscriptionStorage()
                .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
                .InMemoryFaultManagement()
                .InMemorySagaPersister();
        }


        private Type GenerateDynamicType()
        {
            string dcName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MessageClassName"];
            AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName(dcName);
            AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(dcName);

            TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(dcName,TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, typeof(BaseMessageClass));

        }

        public void Start()
        {
            myMessageType = GenerateDynamicType();

            //I tried this method first to get the endpoint set up for this type
            MessageEndpointMappingCollection mappings = new MessageEndpointMappingCollection();
            MessageEndpointMapping m;
            m = new MessageEndpointMapping();
            m.AssemblyName = myMessageType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
            m.Messages = myMessageType.FullName;
            m.Endpoint = "basequeue";
            mappings.Add(m);

            IComponentConfig<UnicastBusConfig> busConfig  = Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<UnicastBusConfig>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None);
            busConfig.ConfigureProperty(u => u.MessageEndpointMappings, mappings);


            //I also tried this from another SO question I found somewhat related, pick one or the other, not both (I think)
            var ucb = Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus>(ComponentCallModelEnum.Singleton);
            ucb.ConfigureProperty(u => u.MessageOwners, new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {myMessageType.AssemblyQualifiedName, "basequeue"}
            });

            //the line below is what throws the error
            Bus.Subscribe(myMessageType, HandleMessage);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            Bus.Unsubscribe(myMessageType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all 50 locations on the same LAN? Or, will those messages need to travel over the NSB gateway?

Comment: they are in the same domain, but going over t1's, which is why I'd like to reduce the messages being sent, but no it won't need a gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built in that will help you much. What you're trying to do is [content based routing](http://www.openamq.org/tutorial%3acontent-based-routing). Regardless of if this is a good idea or not, NSB is not designed to do that out of the box (it's a [unicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast) bus).

I'd suggest taking another direction and decorating [`ISubscriptionStorage`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core/Unicast/Subscriptions/MessageDrivenSubscriptions/ISubscriptionStorage.cs#L25). This interface is used by the [`StorageDrivenPublisher`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/171092bf3084143e512c82210f41f0e15a524fe9/src/NServiceBus.Core/Unicast/Publishing/StorageDrivenPublisher.cs) (which implements [`IPublishMessages`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core/Transports/IPublishMessages.cs)) to get the list of addresses to publish the message to.

Your location number property should become a header, instead of a class property.

A wrapper/decorator could check some parameters (eg. the incoming location number message header) and thin out the `IEnumerable<Address>` returned by the decorated implementation of `GetSubscriberAddressesForMessage`.

An example below decorates `RavenSubscriptionStorage`

```
public class DecoratedSubscriptionStorage : ISubscriptionStorage
{
  public RavenSubscriptionStorage Base { get; set; } //will be injected

  void Subscribe(Address address, IEnumerable<MessageType> messageTypes)
  {
    Base.Subscribe(address, messageTypes);
  }

  void Unsubscribe(Address address, IEnumerable<MessageType> messageTypes)
  {
    Base.Unsubscribe(address, messageTypes);
  }

  IEnumerable<Address> GetSubscriberAddressesForMessage(
                  IEnumerable<MessageType> messageTypes)
  {
    var addresses = Base.GetSubscriberAddressesForMessage(messageTypes);

    //your logic goes here
    return addresses;
  }

  public void Init()
  {
    Base.Init();
  }
}
```

However, your own implementation of this interface could dynamically decorate whatever implementation NSB is using at that moment if configured by the DI framework/bootstrapper.